# Conditional distribution of a discreet variable given a continuous variable

Tags: conditional-probability

I just read a paper mentioned the theorem:

> Let $F$ be a continuous conditional cumulative distribution function of
>   a discrete (categorical) variable $Y$ given a continuous random variable
>   $X$ belong to $[l,u]$....

Sorry but is that possible? I think even conditional distribution of a discrete random variable should still be discrete because it still takes only discrete value. If i am wrong( high chances of this), can you guys give me an example?

Comment: A link to the paper might be useful.

Comment: re the title: "Discreet variables" are delivered in plain brown wrappers.  "Discrete variables" take on values in a completely separated space.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible, take the very basic example: say you conduct a logistic regression analysis, where you predict the binary (discrete) given a level of some toxin in the blood (continuous), so the model is

$$
\Pr(Y = 1) = \mathrm{logit}^{-1}(X\beta) 
$$

We would use such logistic regression model to learn something about the conditional distribution $f(Y \mid X)$, so obviously, there is also $F(Y \mid X)$. If such distribution didn't exist, we wouldn't be able to deal with mixed-type data in probability and statistics (what would lead us to discovering it...).

Comment: hi, what i mean is F(Y|X) here should be discrete, not continuous. I think for your example, F(Y|X) is still discrete.

Comment: @user3513933 F(Y|X) is function of discrete X and continuous Y. I don't know what do you mean by the function being discrete.

Comment: Ok. So i will try to explain as simple as possible. We know about there are 2 types of random variables: discrete and continuous. For discrete, Bernoulli is an example. For continuous, Gaussian is an example. So here what i mean is that Y|X should follow a discrete random distribution, then the cdf(F) here can not be continuous.